# Different output depending on compilation with intellij or sbt

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have the following scala program that simply counts the words in a file:

```
package com.impatient

import java.util.Scanner

object Main extends App {
  countWords()

  def countWords(): Unit = {

    val in = new Scanner(new java.io.File("C:\\tmp\\SampleText.txt"))
    var wc = 0

    while (in.hasNext()) {
      var word = in.next()
      wc += 1
      println( wc + ". " + word)
    }
    in.close()
    println("======================")
    println(s"Total words: $wc")
  }

  def TestFunction(): Unit ={
    println("Hello from test function!")
  }

  TestFunction()
}
```

When I execute this in intellij, either directly or via the sbt shell inside intellij, I get the following output:

> 308. mostly
> 309. positive:
>
> ======================
>
> Total words: 309
>   Hello from test function!

So it correctly counts 309 words in the text file.

However if I try to execute the jar that I just compiled with intellij, directly, either via `scala` or `sbt` I get the following output:

> λ scala .\impatientscala2_2.12-1.0.jar
>
> ======================
>
> Total words: 0
>   Hello from test function!

So in this case, although the methods in `Main` are executed the wordcount is 0.

Why would be this the case? Is intellij referencing some other java libraries that standalone sbt or scala isn't? In that case why doesn't the `Scanner` fail?

***Edit 1***

I have cloned this repo to another PC to see what happens. And in that case I can observe the exact opposite, i.e.:

1. The program returns 0 word count when run from Intellij
2. When the jar is run directly with scala, it gives the current wordcount.

The 0 wordcount is due to not processing the `while` loop, as in.hasNext() returns nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "jar that you just compiled"? It obviously executes some different code (one is with a line break, other is without). So, you are either running some completely wrong jar, or the jar is stale. Clean everything in your IntelliJ, compile **and** *package* everything properly, *then* try to run it with `scala` or whatever.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin thanks for taking a look at this. The line break is just an artifact of SO formatting, I edited the comment bloc. What I mean is this, if I just change the testfunction, compile it inside intellij (sbt shell or directly), then do `sbt run` or scala *.jar outside of intellij, it will correctly reflect the change in the source code, but will not count words. Almost like the scanner function is not working. This I can confirm with the jar timestamp as well. When you say **and package everything properly**, maybe I'm not doing that. If I do `sbt run` inside intellij it counts 309.

Comment: This is not a source of your problem, but you should use native scala classes and idioms. For example, look at `scala.io.Source` for file I/O. Also, you might want to consider accepting the filename as a command-line arg.

Comment: @erip I know. However I would like to understand the cause of this discrepancy.

Comment: Almost certainly the bug comes from the file path. Jars should _rarely_ rely on hardcoded paths.

Comment: @erip It would be a good theory if the path was relative, but even then I'd expect NoSuchFileException. Here, the path is absolute... It's strange. I still suspect some packaging problem. @ OP: You could try describe step by step what you are doing. Those steps should probably start with something like "build -> clean everything", "build -> package" (however it's done in IJ).

Comment: if I change the file name I will get an exception in both cases (in intellij, and directly with scala). My impression is that it has something to do with how intellij sets up the java path. I have added some comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by using `Paths.get` from `java.nio.file._`.

```
//val in = new Scanner(new java.io.File("C:/tmp/SampleText.txt"))
val in: Scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("C/tmp/SampleText.txt"))
```

This produces the correct jars on both PCs, when using Run | Sbt Task in Intellij, using SBT Shell in intellij, and using standalone SBT shell. If anyone can provide an explanation of why would `java.io.File` fail in certain setups that would be great.